# Show that the following polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[t]$ is irreducible and not solvable over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

The polynomial is $f(t)=t^5-4t+2$.

I can show it's irreducible with Eisenstein's Criterion, and I know I need to show that it has exactly two complex (non-real) roots to prove that it's not solvable, using the follow result:

> Let $p>1$ be prime and $f\in\mathbb{Q}[t]$ irreducible with degree $p$. If $f$ has exactly two non-real complex roots, then the Galois group of $f$ is isomorphic to $S_p$. Hence, with $p\geq5$, we have that $f$ is not solvable by radicals over $\mathbb{Q}$.

But I don't know a way to show it has exactly two roots, I know that, using Descartes' rule of signs, we can show that it has at least two complex roots (because it has 2 or 0 positive and one negative real root). Is there something I can use on top of Descartes' rule to make this work? If not, what's the other way?

Comment: A plot of $f(t),t\in [-2,2]$ will give immediately the number of real roots.

Comment: found  https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/generating-the-symmetric-group-with-a-transposition-and-a-maximal-length-cycle/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x) &= +\infty\\
f(1) &= -1\\
f(0) &= 2\\
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) &= -\infty\\
\end{align}
Therefore $f(x)$ has three real roots.
You have shown that $f$ has two complex non-real roots, so you found all roots of $f$.
Then, by the lemma you have proveded it follows that the Galois group of $f$ is $S_5$ and therefore $f$ is not solvable by radicals over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f'(t)=5t^4-4$, $f$ is increasing on $\left(-\infty,-\sqrt[4]{\frac45}\,\right]$ and on $\left[\sqrt[4]{\frac45},\infty\right)$ and decreasing on $\left[-\sqrt[4]{\frac45},\sqrt[4]{\frac45}\,\right]$. But$$f\left(-\sqrt[4]{\frac45}\right)>0\quad\text{and}\quad f\left(\sqrt[4]{\frac45}\right)<0.$$So, $f$ has exactly one real root on each of the three intervals mentioned abov. Since none of them is a double root, it has exactly two complex non-real roots.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ambiguity about the number of real roots, as the second derivative $20 x^3$  is negative for negative $x$  and positive for positive $x.$  In the graph, I was taught to call thse conditions concave down and concave up. The first derivative also has evident roots, $\pm \sqrt[4] \frac{4}{5}.$   It is enough to plot points when $x$ is an integer, although I put in a few more

[image]